# Loop through files in folder and print html content based on the files

Tags: php, html, laravel, vue.js

I am currently learning to use PHP Laravel.
In my current project I have multiple of "same" html code in my template which I want to automate with a loop.

Since I have an image for each project and a language file for each project I had the idea to use a foreach loop in my vue template for each file in my projects images folder or my projects language files folder. This would also make it easier if I want to easily extend the content.

I had something like this in mind.

PHP:

```
<?php
    $files = scandir('../resources/lang/en/project');
    $files2 = scandir('Images/projects');
?>
```

The Template:

```
@foreach($files as $file)
    <div class="row project">
        <div class="col-md-7 order-md-2">
            <h3 class="heading project-heading">{{ __('$file.title') }}<span class="text-muted">{{ __('$file.location') }}</span></h3>
            <p class="lead">{{ __('$file.content') }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 order-md-1">
            <img class="project-image img-fluid mx-auto" src="/Images/projects/$file.jpg" alt="placeholder">
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

This does not work and I am mostly looking for some opinions on how i could tackle this use case.

Comment: Why are you using this way? The better aprovhe is store the path of file in the DB so whenever you need that you can get and pars it or just fetch it.

Comment: atm I am simply learning how to use this and I am trying to get to know the foreach loop and this is my use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before providing my answer to your question, I would recommend you take a step back and [learn the basics of Laravel](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch) before you add additional complexity by using other technologies alongside Laravel. This is just a suggestion and you're on your own learning journey but trying to learn too many things simultaneously can be overwhelming.

Anyway, onward.

Rather than answering your question directly, I'm going to provide a basic example of how you might read, and loop over its contents of a directory. You can then then adapt it for your needs.

Given you have a route defined in your `routes/web.php` file that you'll navigate to in order to show some files:

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    // Using Laravels built in storage helper,
    // get all the files in the 'public/projects/images' folder
    // NOTE: the 'public' folder is symlinked to 'storage',
    // add files to 'storage' rather than 'public'
    $files = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::disk('public')->listContents('projects/images');

    // display a view and pass the files to the view
    return view('file-list', compact('files'));
});
```

Normally the above would be performed in a controller, but I've added it in a route for ease.

**resources/views/file-list.blade.php**

If you were keeping things **really** simple and just wanted to use [`Blade`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade) to start with, you might do the following:

```
<ul>
    @foreach ($files as $file)
        <li>{{ $file['basename'] }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

The `$files` variable which was passed to the view is an `array`, so we loop over the `$files` referring to each element in the `$files` array as `$file` (which is also an array) and for each `$file` element, we display its filename (basename). The other indexes available on `$file` are:

```
  "type" => "file"
  "path" => "projects/images/de.jpg"
  "timestamp" => 1621078308
  "size" => 0
  "dirname" => "projects/images"
  "basename" => "de.jpg"
  "extension" => "jpg"
  "filename" => "de"
```

Note that [`@foreach`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops) is a Blade directive.

I am going to assume you already have Vue installed in your Laravel application, and you know how to add `Vue` components.

Create yourself a new `Vue` component somewhere, for example `resources/js/components/FileListComponent.vue` and register it with your `Vue` instance. Inside your component add the following:

```
<template>
  <ul id="files-list">
    <li v-for="(file, index) in files" :key="index">
        {{ file.basename }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    files: Object,
  }
};
</script>
```

What we have done is create a `Vue` component that expects a `files` [prop](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html) which will be the `$files` we obtained earlier and we will provide it when we use the component. Using the `files` prop, we loop over the files using [`v-for`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/list.html#list-rendering) (which provides equivalent functionality to `@foreach/@for` in Blade) and display the filename for each element just as before.

To use the component, add the component to the `resources/views/file-list.blade.php` view created earlier and provide the `files` prop:

```
<file-list-component :files="{{ json_encode($files) }}" />
```

Assuming you've done everything correctly, you should be shown the same output as before or as well as if you still have the `@foreach` in the blade view.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply but this helped me a long way in my learning process. Thank you!